# How to execute update ($set) queries in MongoDB Compass tool?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I'm new to MongoDB Compass tool and am trying to update a field in my collection. Please can someone suggest where the update query must be written. Could find no options or panes in the tool to write custom queries be it selection / updation for that matter.

In the Default Window only the selection/projection/restriction options are found.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Almost 5 years later and this is still not possible unless using the shell

Comment: I'm also waiting for this feature. The shell simply does not cut it for entering queries and displaying results. It feels like this tool could be open sourced for the benefit of the company and users alike.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In the latest version, there is a "_MongoSH" in the bottom left corner of the window.
Thx to @Boštjan Pišler for the hint about a new feature.

*Old answer*:
I had the same issue, it looks like a simple feature to implement (since document updates are possible) but... AFAIK there is no such option in compass, you can do it through mongodb shell (CLI client).

Comment: Please refer comment from @Bostjan below, looks like there is a way now, although in beta.

Comment: Unfortunately, as of now the option for mongoshell is removed from compass.

Comment: @Mohamedabdelmagid i still see it in latest compass for Linux 1.39.2.

Comment: Oh, thanks, for pointing that out, it seems it was removed for version 1.39.1 on Mac, now that I upgraded it's there again.

Answer (score 47):

The tool was recently updated with a shell (currently in beta) which is accessible by clicking the dark bar on the bottom of the window "_MongoSH"

[image: Mongosh beta tab]

Comment: I'm using compass for months and I realised it now, thanks.

Answer (score 29):

At the bottom left, `_MONGOSH`:

[image: sample-script-mongo]

There you can call `updateMany` and any other methods available in the [MongoSH syntax](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/)

Worth to mention that before running your commands you may want to change the default DB by using `use my-db-name`:

```bash
use book-store-db
# now the variable `db` points to the book-store-db

db.getCollection("books").updateMany({"year":"2022"}, [{ $set: { "price":"0"} }])
```

Comment: worth to add that you need to write `use my-db-name` if the shell is not pointing to your desired db

Comment: Thanks @AnnetteC. I updated the answer to mention it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use mongo MongoSH. Currently its in Beta.

[image]

Answer (score -35):

Just move your mouse over a document and find a little pencil. You will enter in update mode. You can change fields, values, arrays, etc.

Comment: @Pat is obviously asking about a way to execute an update statement, e.g. `db.collection.updateMany()`